# insert text to textarea

Tags: jquery

case: if i `click red image` **>** `add new div`, then if i `click green image` **>** `insert text to textarea`

how can i make this work?
http://jsfiddle.net/AMZMA/tNt7t/11/

i know if i make it to this
http://jsfiddle.net/AMZMA/tNt7t/9/
it works

but it will load image in background cause i'm using `display:none`
i only want load image when i click the `red image`

sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `click()` event on `#image` which will apply to all the images that currently exist in the document and it will not apply on images that you dynamically add in the future. You may use `delegate()` or `on()` to listen for the click event for all `#image` elements that are there now or in the future.

```
  $(document).on('click', "#image",function(event){
        var test = $(event.target).attr("title");
        $(".text").focus().val(test);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tNt7t/20/

---

This might be helpful:

- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
- http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: `live` is deprecated and not needed

Comment: NP, I `$("#parent").on(event, target, func)` is a rough version of the new syntax

Comment: @KevinBowersox yea, I must agree on that. I never succeed at memorizing it's syntax!